# how to make .htaccess slash work?

Tags: .htaccess

I have this: `RewriteRule ^search-(.*)$ search.php?q=$1`
and the outcome is `mysite.com/search-keyword`

What should I do to make the outcome to `mysite.com/search/keyword`

I changed - to / and it worked but the relative urls on my site is broken.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1
```

Then in your `search.php` page's header, add:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: I did that but the relative urls on my site is broken. My css for instance turned into mysite.com/search/style.css from mysite.com/style.css

Comment: Still no success :) :(

Comment: You added a base URL? Try: `<base href="http://example.com/" />` (but using your domain)